# How to change the file path in Download manager - Android(Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I am try to create new file and replace it with current path as this : but the line with ->  .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/NEW_files", name+".png")
make my app crash ;(

```
    val direct = File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/NEW_files"
    )

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs()
    }
   
    val request:DownloadManager.Request=DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse(url)
    ).setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/NEW_files", name+".png")
        .setAllowedOverMetered(true)



    val dm:DownloadManager=getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    dm.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: does it give filenotfound exception?

Comment: `if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs()
    }` That should be: `if (!direct.exists()) {
        if ( !direct.mkdirs() ) return;
    }` but.. you do not have to create that directory as the download manager will do it for you. Well.. if allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and see if this works?

```
val request:DownloadManager.Request=DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse(url)
    ).setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, name+".png")
        .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
```